# CSS Grid How to get grid cells into a new row responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, media-queries, css-grid

I'm trying to make my page responsive. At a certain point my text is overflowing into another grid cell cause there is not enough space. How can I put these cells into a "new" row so the text has space and my other cells are fully visible?

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2MZ7.jpg)

Do I need to add another row into my parent-grid? What is the easiest way to fix this? Best case would be almost no media queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried(HTML, CSS, JS) so like that people can understand well the issue and help you

Comment: If I understand correctly the layout you want, I think I'd implement that with a [float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) rather than a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example by 'adding' another row below the image and text. I suspect you probably don't need the fifth box and it can easily be removed from the code. This is not the responsive part (as we presume you already have that built-in elsewhere in your CSS. Your actual setup may be a 'page grid' versus this example (grid-container), so posting some of your code would help us to visualize a better solution.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  background-color: #2196F3;
  column-gap: 5px;
  row-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial, san-serif;
  color: #000;
}

.grid-item {
  /*--background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); alternative color for all sections--*/
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  background-color: lime;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  background-color: orange;
}

.item5 {
  grid-column: 3 / 3;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item item1">1 image here</div>
  <div class="grid-item item2">2 lots of text here <br>more text <br>more text <br>more text </div>
  <div class="grid-item item3">3 link</div>  
  <div class="grid-item item4">4 link</div>
  <div class="grid-item item5">5 link</div>
</div>
```